# Selecting Elements of dropbox via VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am working in excel, and my purpose is to create a drop-box(at cell say `D4`) of certain values present in range (say)`A1:A3`. Now using `VBA`, while selecting each Item from the drop down list, it should display a particular message. When I choose an item from the drop-box, compiler shows no error but at the same time, it displays nothing.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Select Case Range("D4")
     Case "Item 1"
      MsgBox ("Item 1")
     Case "Item 2"
      MsgBox ("Item 2")
     Case "Item 3"
      MsgBox ("Item 3")
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: its because you using `sheetChange` event. Are you using form controls or activex dropdown?

Comment: I am using Data Validation to create DropBox and VBA to code it.

Comment: Hmm then im not sure what you try to achieve. Data validation will not create dropbox, its only for cell value limitation... But if you wana to validate input value of combobox, i would use rather VBA than data validation. Or if you need data validation, try to pin worksheetCalculate event after dropbox value change

Comment: did you try as per my suggestion?

Comment: I used this Sub, Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range). Customized using Select Case and it worked.

Comment: Suit yourself. But using a data validation in UI would call for Validation object once in VBA

Answer (score 0):

you can exploit [Validation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821214.aspx) object like follows

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    With Range("D4")            
        If .Validation.IgnoreBlank And IsEmpty(.Cells) Or Not .Validation.Value Then
            MsgBox ("no Item selected")
        Else
            MsgBox ("Item " & WorksheetFunction.Match(.Value, Range(.Validation.Formula1), 0))
        End If            
    End With    
End Sub
```